# Does this C++ code produce an undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

A have found the following snippet:

```
int a[100];
...
int value = 42[a];
```

Which appears to do exactly what `a[42]` does.

Is it a bogus with undefined behavior or a perfectly legal C++ code?

Comment: @TemplateRex: it takes time to find this kind of answers unless you already know the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's perfectly legal. With pointer arithmetic, `a[42]` is equivalent to `*(a + 42)`, which (addition being commutative) is equivalent to `*(42+ a)`, which (by definition of `[]`) is equivalent to `42[a]`.

So it's obscure, but well-defined.

Comment: Just a small question: is it perfectly legal **in C++** and not just in C, but still works in C++ because legacy ?

Comment: @JBL I don't see a single mention of C in the question or in my answer. This is perfectly legal C++.

Comment: Yes I know, but was just wondering. Still I found in §5.2.1/1 what I was looking for (that it's the exact same thing as it's in C). Dunno why I somehow thought it was different... My mistake.

Comment: @JBL I know why: because it is such a silly language feature that only seems to exist for clever questions and confusion.  Even if you know that it came from pointer arithmatic.

Comment: You'll find it regularly used (in C) in the code at http://www.ioccc.org/.

Comment: @stefaanv Erm, I have a small doubt there. It's indeed how the language works that a[i] is an equivalent of *(a+i).It's just that i[a] is a silly side effect of how subscripting works (well, to be really precise, **it's a side effect of addition commutativity** somewhat). I don't think it does exist just for "clever questions" IMO... :/

Comment: @JBL sorry, sarcasm (a bit like James' comment). If C/C++ were to be redesigned, it shouldn't be in the language definition because it just adds confusion and questions like this one.  Anyway, I thought it was a great reason why you were allowed to doubt whether it was legal in C++.

Answer (score 5):

The array operator is *commutative*.

`a[n] ==  *(a + n) == *(n + a) == n[a]`

And it's perfectly legal.

Comment: Does that mean ``a`` is just always treated as pointer?

Comment: @SergeyK. No. It means that in some operations which are applicable to pointers, but not arrays, `a` is treated as a pointer. In some other operations, such as `sizeof(a)`, or `&a`, it is not. @ᴍaroun ᴍaroun -- No, they are not. (in response to the deleted comment that arrays are constant pointers)

Answer (score 3):

`a[i]` is defined as `*(a+i)`.

So `42[a]`=`a[42];` and it is perfectly safe

Answer (score 1):

`42[a]` is exactly equivalent to `a[42]`, and entirely legal. It works because a pointer address is just an integer underneath, so you can do the arithmetic either way round (an array variable is really just a pointer in a thin disguise).

It's not usually a good idea for readability though, unless you're deliberately trying to obfuscate the code.